# Floating point exception (core dumped) in C

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, scanf, fedora

While writing a C program and compiling it in fedora 32, I always get this message `Floating point exception (core dumped)` when I try to scan user's input from the terminal, and I don't know what i did wrong.

I put some `printf` functions in between to know where it stops, and what I found that `scanf ("%i", &number);` function doesn't read the input or save it correctly.

This is some of the code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int number, constant, remain, remain1, mod, count, test;
    
    number = 0;
    mod = 1;
    count = 0;

    printf ("Enter a number to write: \n");
    scanf ("%i", &number);
    
    printf ("-1");
    
    constant = number;
    test = number;
    printf ("0");
    if (number < 0)
    {
        number = number * -1;
        printf ("-");
    }
    printf ("1");
    while (test != 0)
    {
        test /= 10;
        count++;
        printf ("%i", count);
    }
    printf ("2");
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        mod = mod * 10; 
    }
    printf ("3");
    while (number != 0)
    {
        
        remain = number % mod;
        remain1 = constant - remain * mod;
        
        switch (remain)
        {
            case 0:
                printf ("Zero");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf ("One");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf ("Two");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf ("Three");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf ("Four");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf ("Five");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf ("Six");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf ("Seven");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf ("Eight");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf ("Nine");
                break;
        }

        remain = remain1;
        mod /= 10;
    }
    
        printf ("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: replace `scanf(...)` with `char temp[1000]; if (!fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); if (sscanf(temp, "%i", &number) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "error reading number from %s", temp); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: so, the problem is **NOT** with the `scanf()` call

Comment: Yes you are right.
I think the problem is in the rest of it when it gets to the switch statement.
I'll search about the problem and tell you what I found.

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: yes I know but didn't reach it's chapter yet. I am studying from a book.

Comment: You use %f but number is int

Comment: It's a mistake didn't mean to put it. sorry, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT as for my original guess - it is division by zero

```
        if(!mod ) // add this if 
             {printf("Division by zero");exit(0);} //
        remain = number % mod;
```

---

Always check the result of the `scanf`. Yuo do not have  any floating point opertions here, but probably you have division by zero somewhere in the code you did not show.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int number, constant, remain, remain1, mod, count, test;
    
    number = 0;
    mod = 1;
    count = 0;

    printf ("Enter a number to write: \n");
    if(scanf ("%i", &number) != 1)
    {
        printf("scanf error\n");
    }
    else
    {    
        printf ("-1");
        
        constant = number;
        test = number;
        printf ("0");

        if (number < 0)
        {
            number = number * -1;
            printf ("-");
        }

        printf ("1");

        while (test != 0)
        {
            test /= 10;
            count++;
            printf ("%i", count);
        }

        printf ("2");

        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            mod = mod * 10; 
        }
    }
}
```

Here you have this function made simple:

```
char *digits[] = {"Zero","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"};

void printWord(int x)
{
    int work = x;
    long val = 1;
    while(work)
    {
        val *= 10;
        work /= 10;
    }
    val /= 10;
    if(x < 0) printf("Minus");
    if(!x) val = 10;
    do
    {
        printf("%s", digits[abs(x / val)]);
        x %= val;
        val /= 10;
    }while(x);
}

int main (void)
{
    printWord(0);    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q4oWqT

Comment: Your code is working, but when I put it with the rest of mine I shows the same problem, so I think the problem is in the switch statement, i'll try to search for the problem again.

Comment: show us the rest of the code.There is no other way to help ypu

Comment: I'll put it in an answer.

Comment: @AhmedRifaat read the answer. You have division by zero. you can't do `something % 0`

Comment: You are right, it's a division by zero. thank you for your help.

Comment: Fails with large `x` as `val *= 10;` overflows.  Try `printWord(INT_MIN/10);`, `printWord(INT_MIN);`  (Aside: suggest spell check too).

Comment: Perhaps `int work = abs(x/10); int val = 1; while(work >= val) { val *= 10; } if(x < 0) printf("Minus");  do ...`

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
mod /= 10;
```

eventually results in `mod` containing 0.  Then this statement:

```
remain = number % mod;
```

results in a division by 0 operation

Comment: Yes, you are right, I managed to solve it finally and it's working fine now.